# Access to fetch at 'http://localhost/drupal/webform_rest/submit?_format=json' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: reactjs, drupal, cors, drupal-webform

I am setting up a real estate site with react-gatsby as front end and drupal 9 as backend.

I have contact us form in gatsby website, I want send the details to drupal webform REST to save the user's details like name, email and mobile.

The GET and POST request works fine in Postmen app but when fill the details on my contact us form click submit it giving me the following error.

This is gatsby contact us form code:-

```
    import React from 'react'
import '../css/Style.css';

const Contactus = () => {
  function handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event);
    const name = event.target.name.value;
    const email = event.target.email.value;
    const mobile = event.target.mobile.value;
    console.log(name);
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: myHeaders,
        redirect: 'follow'
      };
    myHeaders.append("X-CSRF-Token", "AHIK9FOi8FZscSQURECT6CfCCRgUcm0nNiaDxnvnEus");
//  myHeaders.append("Cookie", "SESS29af1facda0a866a687d5055f2fade2c=NsWpmKXyQRxGanB5%2CNEy7hpTY7nFc8xcTdLp100Zf2PiLCMx");
    var raw = JSON.stringify({
      "webform_id": "contact",
      "entity_type": null,
      "entity_id": null,
      "in_draft": false,
      "uri": [
        "/webform/webform_id/api"
      ],
      "name": name,
      "email": email,
      "mobile": mobile
    });
    
    var requestOptions2 = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: raw,
      redirect: 'follow'
    };
    
    fetch("http://localhost/drupal/webform_rest/submit?_format=json",requestOptions2)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  }
  return (
    <>
                <div className='contactus'>
                    <div className='contactusInfo'>
                        <h3>For Any Query</h3>
                        <span>CONTACT US AT</span>
                        <h3>Sunteck World,</h3>
                        <h3>Sunteck world, Naigaon East, Mumbai, Maharashtra 401208,</h3>
                        <h3>Phone : +91 9702020907,</h3>
                    </div>
                    <form className='contactusform' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <h2>Please Enter Your Details Below</h2>
                            <div className='inputArea'>
                                <input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Enter Your Name' className='inputName' />
                                <input type='phone' name='mobile' placeholder='Enter Your Mobile Number' className='inputMobile' />
                                <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='Enter Your Email' className='inputEmail' />
                                <button type='submit' className='submit-btn'>Submit</button>
                            </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </>
  )
}

export default Contactus
```

On drupal I am using web form :

[image]

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost/drupal/webform_rest/submit?_format=json' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I have tried to make the changes in drupal 9 services.yml file but its not working

```
cors.config:
    enabled: true
    # Specify allowed headers, like 'x-allowed-header'.
    allowedHeaders: ['access-control-allow-origin','content-type']
    # Specify allowed request methods, specify ['*'] to allow all possible ones.
    allowedMethods: ['POST']
    # Configure requests allowed from specific origins.
    allowedOrigins: ['http://localhost:8000']
    # Sets the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.
    exposedHeaders: false
    # Sets the Access-Control-Max-Age header.
    maxAge: false
    # Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.
    supportsCredentials: false
```

Can anyone help me solve this error? Thank you!